# Installed Nvidia driver got blank screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I'm having the problem with updating Nvidia. After updating the driver, I logged in and got a blank screen. I can change my background, but not much else. I can't even get to the terminal to do anything.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it sends me to this black screen that asks for my login and password. I've put in my correct information, but I still can't login.

Comment: It seems as though my video driver has crashed and taken Ubuntu along with it.

Comment: what is your graphics card?  Is it optimus enabled system? There can not be any issue for username/password due to driver installation.

Comment: which version of ubuntu are you using? I saw another question from you with same problem where you have mentioned you are using 12.10. If so please remember 12.10 is still in alpha stage and its expected to break

Comment: I was using 12.04, but after I installed the driver, it said I was using 12.10. I have an Intel GMA graphics card. I've heard there were problems with updating nvidia, but all the fixes include using the terminal, which I can't pull up.

Comment: if you are haveing Intel GMA card why are installing nvidia? Have you enabled ubuntu update to fetch 12.10 ? See [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-from-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: I'm really computer illiterate. I was having problems shutting down my computer and the person who installed ubuntu on my computer said it had something to do with my graphics driver being out of date. I just followed what some forum said and installed nvidia. I'm pretty sure I'm doing some very stupid things.

Comment: I would suggest to do a fresh install. :(

Comment: I'm thinking that as well. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

What does `lspci | grep VGA` output? It might be the same issues a bunch of people are having with broken 3D on a certain series of nv30 hardware.

Does ubuntu-2d work?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/964275

Sadly because nvidia driver is closed source there isn't much we (people that don't work for Nvidia) can do to fix it. However the nouveau driver works well for 2d. (and the 3d rewrite in mesa is coming along)